# Enabling jQuery Intellisense inside JavaScript file in Webmatrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense, webmatrix

I have done the following in WebMatrix.

I imported jQuery inside my HTML page with documentation of jQuery and successfully enabled jQuery intellisense inside the HTML `script` tag.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="JS/jquery-2.1.0.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="JS/jquery-2.1.0-vsdoc.js" ></script>
```

Now I want to enable jQuery intellisense inside my external JavaScript file,How would it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, in Visual Studio you can use **reference** directive in the beginning of the file. It will include a script file in the scripting context of the current script file. And IntelliSense will be enabled. Since WebMatrix is microsoft as well, I believe this should work too:

```
/// <reference path="JS/jquery-2.1.0.js" />
/// <reference path="JS/jquery-2.1.0-vsdoc.js" />
```

if **path** attribute won't work, try **file** attribute.

http://yadi.sk/d/Szhp8tOJNLXYu
[image: example]

Comment: Where to put that code.I mean in html or js?I have tried putting it in both but that didnot work either.

Comment: yes, in JS file. You were asking about JS files, no? I added a screenshot.

Comment: this helped me. just needed to set the correct path relative to that js file.

Comment: I've done this reference by dragging and dropping in my JS file and I still don't have intellisense for jQuery even after reloading the project. Ugh...